# mysql- how to order by latest entry out of two different column

Tags: mysql, filtering

I am looking for the solution. In mysql DB I have two columns up1 and up2 I would like the data to be ordered DESC by the column in which there is the latest data entry. Sometimes it would be up1 sometimes up2. Please can you suggest me how to make it. Thx.

I am looking for the solution. In mysql DB I have two columns up1 and up2 I would like the data to be ordered DESC by the column in which there is the latest data entry. Sometimes it would be up1 sometimes up2. Please can you suggest me how to make it. Thx.

so this is how DB looks in myphpadmin

```
+-------+-------+
|  up1  |  up2  |
+-------+-------+
| 26.09 | 24.09 |
| 22.09 | 23.09 |
+-------+-------+
```

But I would like the end user to see only one column with the latest update entry in above case:

```
+--------+
| result |
+--------+
|  26.09 |
+--------+
```

But in below case

```
+-------+-------+
|  up1  |  up2  |
+-------+-------+
| 26.09 | 27.09 |
| 22.09 | 23.09 |
+-------+-------+
```

it would be like this

```
   +--------+
    | result |
    +--------+
    |  27.09 |
    +--------+
```

Comment: Which column records the date of the data?  Have you tried something yet?

Comment: Please show some sample data and the desired result. It's hard to tell from your description.

Comment: this query is working `SELECT up1, up2 FROM DB ORDER BY GREATEST (up1, up2) DESC;`

Answer (score 1):

The `GREATEST` function will return the most recent date from the two columns, and you can use this for ordering.

```
ORDER BY GREATEST(up1, up2) DESC
```